# Use osmar to load all data from an OSM file

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmar

The standard workflow for osmar is:

```
src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = "my_place.osm")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 3000, 3000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
```

But what if I want to load all of the data from `myplace.osm` and don't know a priori the bounding box?

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of getting the bounding box which contains all the data, or of telling `get_osm`  to load everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used default box corner arguments for osmosis:

```
muc_bbox <- corner_bbox(left = -180, right = 180, top = 90, bottom = -90)
```